# how can I replace a string in a text file in assembly 8086?

Tags: assembly

I want to write a program that will open a file, search for a specified string and replace the string with another one. 
My idea is to read the file 16 byte at a time (my string is of 16 byte), check whether it matches to the specified one. If yes, then move file pointer 16 byte backward, replace 16 byte with spaces, again move file pointer 16 byte backward to fill this 16 byte with the new string
But its not working properly. Can anyone help me to solve this?

this is the procedure where I am taking input and trying to replace with previous one.

```
edit1 proc
    pushf
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx
    push di

    mov ah, 42h
    mov al, 1
    mov cx, -1
    mov dx, -18
    int 21h

    mov ah, 40h
    mov cx, 18
    mov dx, offset space1
    int 21h

    mov ah, 42h
    mov al, 1
    mov cx, -1
    mov dx, -18
    int 21h

    number_input1:  ;taking input string with which I want to replace
    mov ah, 01h
    lea di, number1
    cld  

    number_loop1:
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0dh
    je    write1 
    stosb
    jmp number_loop1 

    write1:
    mov ah, 40h
    mov cx, 18
    lea dx, number1
    int 21h 

    pop di
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    popf
    ret 
edit1 endp
```

Comment: If you want people to help show your code

Comment: There's no need to write spaces to disk and then overwrite again with your string. Just write the string itself. If this is done because the string may be _up to_ 16 bytes long, and you  wish to ensure the old string is removed entirely, simply use a 16 byte buffer in memory, fill it with spaces, copy your string to it and then write the buffer to disk once. I realize this doesn't answer your question. Also, "does not work properly" is a really poor description of the problem. You really need to describe what is expected and what is observed - we cant see your screen!

Comment: In a file, there will be a name(16 byte), contact number(16 byte) and new line(2 byte : 0ah, 0dh). Every time I want to edit a number, at a time it will read 34 byte and check if the first 16 byte matches with the given name. then if it matches, then replace the corresponding contact no with the new one. 
but after running the code, the name of the file like "A.txt" is written in the file in emu8086, even in masm it generates ambiguous characters in the console.

Comment: *But its not working properly.* Could you please explain exactly what's not working? In your subsequent comment, it's a little unclear as well (I'm not sure what *it generates ambiguous characters in the console* means). As @Fifoernik mentions in his answer, you haven't set the file handle for your file IO. But perhaps you are passing it into the function via `bx` after you did an open? It's unclear. And `bx` will get overwritten by some `int 21h` calls, so you need to be mindful of that.

Comment: I've passed handle in bx register, but problem hasn't been solved yet. 
Like if I give input : Hello 12345
Then want to replace that number with 45678,  
In the file it is written like "Hello         45678            H." (without double quote)

Comment: @HosnearaAhmed I added info to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- All of your DOS calls seem to lack the BX parameter.
  This should hold a handle to your opened file!
- Based on your last comment, consider this example:

  Your *number_loop1* input loop gets these 11 characters (and then a return):

  ```
  Hello 12345
  ```

  Hereafter your *write1* code **always writes 18 bytes** no matter the number of characters that were inputted (here 11). This will inevitably lead to garbage bytes in the file (here 7).

  Solution:
  You've written 18 spaces in the file but you should have written 18 spaces in the memory pointed at by *number1*.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my example probably was not perfect to express the actual condition. In the file it always writes 18 bytes as the string is initialized to spaces. 
As I am trying to move backward from the current position, at first I sought the current file pointer location and then move forward from starting point of the file to that position. As previous approach was a failure, now I've tried this way and it works. 
Thanks to all.